# Command line option 'r' [from -r‘] is not known

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda, kernel, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). The tutorial is [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda5.5-ubuntu). When I am trying to install the required headers, I get an error.

This is my command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-‘uname -r‘
```

This is the output

```
root@ubuserver3:/home/ubuadmin# sudo apt-get install linux-headers-‘uname -r‘
E: Command line option 'r' [from -r‘] is not known.
```

What has happened? I am not a Linux person, FYI. I am just copying and pasting those commands from the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The `uname -r` is a linux command that is supposed to be executed prior to the execution of the apt-get command.

In order to make this work you need to use back-tick characters, not the forward-single-quote characters.

On my keyboard, the back-tick is on the upper left corner key on the same key as ~:

this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

not this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-‘uname -r‘
```

Answer (score 0):

try 'uname -a'

It will tell you what version you have to download